# rails ActiveModel add attribure that is not persisted

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, find-by-sql

I am trying to query model table:

```
> messages = Message.find_by_sql("select count(*) as messages_count,
> sender_id, recipient_id, min(is_read) as is_read from messages group
> by sender_id, recipient_id")
```

DB table contains fields sender_id, recipient_id, is_read.
As the result I've got an arrays of hashes where messages_count is not present.

I tried in my

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def attributes
    super.merge('messages_count' => self.messages_count)
  end

  after_initialize do
    self.messages_count = nil unless @attributes.key?("messages_count")
  end
```

also I tried to override get hash like this

```
  def serializable_hash(options = {})

  end
```

this was not triggered.

What can I try else? Thanks!

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: What i've got [#<Message id: nil, is_read: false, sender_id: 409608538, recipient_id: 762146111>, #<Message id: nil, is_read: false, sender_id: 409608538, recipient_id: 950961012>, #<Message id:
 nil, is_read: true, sender_id: 762146111, recipient_id: 409608538>]
But my idea was to obtain something like 
[#<Message id: nil, **message_count: 3**, is_read: false, sender_id: 409608538, recipient_id: 762146111>]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313067/activerecordbase-connection-select-all-hash-error).

```
messages = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
                 .select_all("select count(*) as messages_count,
                           sender_id, recipient_id, min(is_read) as is_read
                           from messages group by sender_id, recipient_id").to_a
```

Returns:

```
[{"messages_count"=>3, "sender_id"=>409608538, "recipient_id"=>762146111, "is_read"=>"f"}, {"messages_count"=>1, "sender_id"=>409608538, "recipient_id"=>950961012, "is_read"=>"f"},
 {"messages_count"=>2, "sender_id"=>762146111, "recipient_id"=>409608538, "is_read"=>"t"}]
```